# Interpreting a matrix calculation

Tags: linear-algebra

I recently came across this problem, although trivial to compute by hand - is a little challenging for me to interpret. Notably, we have three matrices:

$$\vec{c}=
  \begin{bmatrix}
    0.5 \\
    0.5
  \end{bmatrix},\hspace{0.2in} 
  \vec{x}=
  \begin{bmatrix}
    2 \\
    3
  \end{bmatrix},\hspace{0.2in} 
  \vec{\mu}=
    \begin{bmatrix}
    1 \\
    2 
  \end{bmatrix}, \hspace{0.2in}
 \mathbf{\Sigma} = 
  \begin{bmatrix}
    2 & 1 \\
    1 & 4 
  \end{bmatrix}
$$

We then have the following calculation, which I have solved below.

$\vec{c}^{\,T}(\vec{x}-\vec{\mu}) (\vec{c}^{\ T}\mathbf{\Sigma}\vec{c})^{-1}$
${}=\begin{bmatrix}
     \
    0.5
  \end{bmatrix}$

The calculation is trivial. However, how do I interpret this solution - assuming $\vec{x}$ is a data vector, $\vec{\mu}$ is a mean vector, and  $\mathbf{\Sigma}$ is a covariance matrix?

Comment: Hint: think of standardization and consider the variance of $\vec{c}^\prime \vec{x}.$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider the random variable $$y = c^T x$$Then the mean of $y$ is 
$$E(y) = c^T E(x) = c^T \mu$$
and variance of $y$ is
$$var(y) = E(y - c^T \mu)^2 = E(y^2) - (c^T \mu)^2 = E(y^2) + c^T \mu\mu^T c \tag{*}$$
But
$$y^2 = (c^Tx)^2 = c^Tx c^Tx= c^Txx^Tc$$
So $$E(y^2) = c^TE(xx^T)c = c^T(\Sigma - \mu\mu^T)c \tag{**}$$
Replace $(**)$ is $(*)$, we get
$$var(y) = c^T\Sigma c$$
Let $z$ be a standard version of $y$, i.e.
$$z = \frac{y - E(y)}{var(y)} = \frac{c^Tx - c^T\mu}{c^T\Sigma c} = c^T(x - \mu)(c^T\Sigma c)^{-1} $$
So, you have computed the $z$ here.